# Is the past string removed when changing from StringPool to java String?

Tags: java, string

I can't understand, if I change a string in java, will the previous string be removed from the StringPool or will it remain?

```
Sting s1 = "hello";
s1 = "test";
```

I understand that when you change a string in java, the object does not change, but simply the link begins to refer to the newly created object.Will the "hello" value in the StringPool end up being removed?

Comment: you don't "change" a String. You merely reassign the variable. This snippet is a very minimal bit of code. It might be that "hello" is still referenced somewhere. If it isn't, it might is ready to be garbage collected (by the jvm), but we can't tell if that's the case here.

Comment: In this case,  both "hello" and "test" will be in the string pool as soon as the class file is loaded.

Comment: @MauricePerry the question is whether or not "hello" will be removed from the String pool once the variable is reassigned

Comment: @Stultuske yes. My guess is that, as they are both literal strings, they would both be referenced in the class file. However, the compiler could see that "hello" is never used, and could then discard it altogether. As you said, we can't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

## TLDR;

Yes, Strings that are not used (used meaning, referenced by another object) will be removed, like any other out-of-scope object.

## Longer Version

*But how do we know for sure?*

Usually, let's see what the Java Specification says; my brief search found nothing.

Next, let's dive into the standard Java implementation, but the String class also did not help, as the clean-up of Strings is managed within the JVM's implementation.

So, finally - if you are curious about how the String Pool marks objects as out of scope, here is the [JDK 8 implementation.](https://hg.openjdk.org/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/classfile/symbolTable.cpp#l742)

```
void StringTable::unlink_or_oops_do(BoolObjectClosure* is_alive, OopClosure* f) {
  // Readers of the table are unlocked, so we should only be removing
  // entries at a safepoint.
  assert(SafepointSynchronize::is_at_safepoint(), "must be at safepoint");
  for (int i = 0; i < the_table()->table_size(); ++i) {
    HashtableEntry<oop, mtSymbol>** p = the_table()->bucket_addr(i);
    HashtableEntry<oop, mtSymbol>* entry = the_table()->bucket(i);
    while (entry != NULL) {
      assert(!entry->is_shared(), "CDS not used for the StringTable");

      if (is_alive->do_object_b(entry->literal())) {
        if (f != NULL) {
          f->do_oop((oop*)entry->literal_addr());
        }
        p = entry->next_addr();
      } else {
        *p = entry->next();
        the_table()->free_entry(entry);
      }
      entry = *p;
    }
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: I am no C++ Developer, but from what I understand is, the code runs through all the String objects and checks if there is a back reference to the String object, if not it frees up the String (entry).

**Random thing:** The Code refers to a StringTable and not the String Pool :) So now you can correct all your friends ;)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot change values of Strings, strings are constant. When you reassign your string `s1` to the value "test", the previous value ("hello") still remains in the String Pool but won't be removed. It will stay there until it's permitted for garbage collection, that will happen, when it's no longer referenced.